# how to check value of variable has changed or not inside while loop without comparing inside java

Tags: java, database, while-loop

i am fetching value from data base which is overriding the old value , how could in know when the variable value has changed.

```
while(result.next())
{
String rteCd = result.getString("Rte_Cd")
}
```

every time the rteCd will get get overridden with the database value, i want to check at which point it has changed becoz it can be same also, i need to perform some action when it changes

Npte:- i cant change the database and the query can return same value multiple times

Comment: Simplest way: Use a second variable!

Comment: Can you include the query you are running to put these requirements into context?

Comment: Set a variable "lastRteCd" at the end of the loop.  Then compare rteCd to lastRteCd.  If they are different do whatever needs to be done.

Comment: What do you mean by "without comparing" ? Why do you neeed to do this typical comarision job without comparing? These questions make you question unclear.

Comment: There's next to no information here. What database even?

Comment: nothing is being overridden. the String rteCd only exists inside the scope of that loop. a new one is created. even before the assigning, the second time you run your loop, the rteCd reference variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Are the column Rte_Cd values sorted? Can you give example of how the data (just the Rte_Cd column) values might look like (for example: "A", "B", "X", "A", "A", "X", "Y"...

Comment: only thing i am asking is how to get to know when a variable value changes

Comment: result is Query Result and is not sorted

Comment: is there a way to go to just previous record of DB2 database

Answer (score 0):

Java.util.Observable might be of help.
The java.util.Observable.hasChanged() method returns if this object has changed.
Here's a sample code you can check out

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

class ObservedObject extends Observable {
   private String watchedValue;

   public ObservedObject(String value) {
      watchedValue = value;
   }

   public void setValue(String value) {

      // if value has changed notify observers
      if(!watchedValue.equals(value)) {
         watchedValue = value;

         // mark as value changed
         setChanged();
      }
   }
}
public class ObservableDemo implements Observer {
   public String name;

   public ObservableDemo(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create watched and watcher objects
      ObservedObject watched = new ObservedObject("Original Value");

      // watcher object listens to object change
      ObservableDemo watcher = new ObservableDemo("Watcher");

      // add observer to the watched object
      watched.addObserver(watcher);

      // trigger value change
      System.out.println("setValue method called...");
      watched.setValue("New Value");

      // check if value has changed
      if(watched.hasChanged())
      System.out.println("Value changed");
      else
      System.out.println("Value not changed");
   }

   public void update(Observable obj, Object arg) {
      System.out.println("Update called");
   }
}
```

Output

setValue method called...
Value changed

Comment: its a variable not an object, how we can do it for variable

Comment: I dont know what database you want to watch. The size of it etc etc. To simply watch for the changes of values you need to create ObservedObject  object for each of them. If database size is huge you need to go for equality checking. Because create this many objects will throw HeapSpace out of memeory exception.

Answer (score -1):

Declare two more variable outside the while loop and then see the old and new value like this

```
String oldvalue="";
     String newvalue="";
     while(result.next())
     {
     oldvalue=rteCd;
     String rteCd = result.getString("Rte_Cd")
     newvalue=rteCd;
     }
//Now Display them
println("old value"+oldvalue);
println("new value"+newvalue);
```

Comment: he said he Needs to do some Action when they change

Comment: @Vishal re-read your code, and see if you can spot why this doesn't meet the requirements. let's assume the last two values that are read would be identical, your code would "verify" that the value was never changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
String prevRteCd = null;
String rteCd = null;
while(result.next())
{
    prevRteCd = rteCd;
    rteCd = result.getString("Rte_Cd");
    if(prevRteCd! =null &&  !prevRteCd.equals(rteCd))
    {
        itChanged(prevRteCd, rteCd);
    } 
 }
```

Comment: "without comparing", meaning equals is not a valid option

Comment: As the query is changing the string value everytime so equal will not work

Comment: You mean you need a trigger in java? Because what you do with that loop is something else.